# How to apply a logical operator to all elements in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, operators

I need to apply the `&&` (logical and) operator to all elements in the list. The problem is: In my current solution, I need to initialize the `rowResult` variable, and I think the result may become invalid because of the variable having an initial value.

```
ArrayList<Boolean> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (i = 1; i < results.size(); i++) {
    rowResult = rowResult && results.get(i);
}
```

Comment: Well it looks like you should be initializing it to `true` before the loop - in which case it will stay true so long as there aren't any `false` values in the list. Is that what you want? Is there any reason you're ignoring the first element of the list btw? (I'd also suggest using the enhanced for loop...) Oh, and you can optimize this by stopping as soon as you hit a `false` value.

Comment: "then rowResult can become incorrect" << why? The neutral value for the AND operation is `true` (`x AND true` never changes `x`), so initializing it to `true` should do the trick just fine.

Comment: Thx you guys @JonSkeet and @CherryDT, thats what i think about it:
if 'rowResult' is true, then in case 'results' has 3x 'FALSE' the 'rowResult' will be 'TRUE'. And this is incorrect. I need `FALSE || FALSE || FALSE == FALSE`

Comment: @P.Savrov: No, if `rowResult` is true, and you use `rowResult = rowResult && false`, then it will become `false`.

Comment: my mistake, sorry man. I wanted to find one decision for AND and OR operations. For AND case you are absolutly right

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already noted by Jon Skeet or CherryDT you can initialize your rowResult with true. Then your code could look like:

```
boolean rowResult = true;
for (Boolean el: list) {
    rowResult = el && rowResult;
}
```

In case one would like to use operator`OR` - `||` the initial value should be set to `false` and operator to `||`.

---

In Java 8 you can apply use `reduce` method for streams:

```
List<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<>();
boolean rowResult = list.stream().reduce((a,b)-> a && b).orElse(true);
```

The latter has this advantage that you can apply any logical operator instead of `&&`.

In the java 8 example one can just change the operator to e.g `||` to apply `OR`. The value in `orElse` statement is just for the case when list is empty.

Comment: but what if list contain all false values? rowResult should be false, but TRUE || FALSE || FALSE || FALSE || ... == TRUE

Comment: In your original question you posted operator `AND` - `&&` not `OR` - `||`. For `OR` change the initial value to `false` and operator to `||`. In the java 8 example just change the operator. The value in orElse statement is just for the case when list is Empty.

Comment: @dwysakowicz Can you please append your answer accordingly? Comments can be missed and this is a vital information for solving OPs question :).

Comment: @Tom I think this time the answer covers all OPs problems ;)

Answer (score 9):

In Java 8, you can use streams:

```
boolean rowResult = results.stream().allMatch(b -> b);
```

Before Java 8, there was Guava:

```
boolean rowResult = Iterables.all(results, new Predicate<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(Boolean input) {
        return input;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just note, that at least the pre java 8 version is vulnerable to a NullPointerException.

Comment: Removing that annotation doesn't avoid the vulnerability :P.

Comment: I know, I didn't mean it like that :D. I absolutely agree, the code is vulnerable to NPE. It was just misleading to have the annotation there.

Comment: Well in my opinion it is quite nice to have that annotation there, so the programmer remembers that each item from the list _can_ be `null`. But that's a matter of taste :).

Answer (score 4):

In java 8+ you can also use the `reduce` instead of the `allMatch`. To my opinion it is cleaner:

`boolean result = results.stream().reduce(Boolean::logicalAnd).orElse(false);`

You can replace the `logicalAnd` with the operator you need. The `Boolean` class has all operators.